# nginx rewrite rule (convert segments to get paramters)

Tags: mod-rewrite, nginx, rules

I need

```
/secure/token/timestamp/path/to/the/resource/
```

to be rewritten in this format:

```
/s/path/to/the/resource/?st=token&e=timestamp
```

what I'm trying to do is:

```
location /secure/(?<token>)/(?<timestamp>)/(?<path>) {
    rewrite ^ /s/$path/?st=$token&e=$timestamp
}
```

but it's obviously not working. This syntax doesn't seemed to be correct. How can I play like this with urls in nginx rules?

EDIT:
trying now something like this: the same result:

```
     location /secure/(.*)/(.*)/(.*) {
         rewrite ^ /s/$3?st=$1token&e=$2timestamp;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple problems. You have confused prefix locations with regex locations. Your named captures do not contain any content. And your numeric captures are probably too broad.

See [this](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for location syntax.

You should probably use a prefix location, then capture in the rewrite:

```
location /secure/ {
    rewrite ^/secure/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/(.*)$ /s/$3?st=$1&e=$2 last;
}
```

Comment: Hi Richard, How we can do the same thing in opposite way. I want to convert get parameters to segments?

Comment: @AkshayDeshmukh see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54329332/nginx-redirect-url-with-query-strings/54330947#54330947).