# NGINX Redirect URL with Query Strings

Tags: linux, nginx, configuration, webserver

I have this NGINX configuration:

```
root    /var/www/web;
index   index.php;

server_name  domain.com;
access_log  off;
error_log on;

location / {
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?tag=$1&page=1 last;
}
```

Now, I want to redirect url something like 
"domain.com/index.php?tag=1&section=2&type=3" to "domain.com/tag/section/type"

how can I do that, where should I put the code? please help,

Thankyou

I already tried:

```
location / {
   rewrite ^/index\.php?tag=(.*)&section=(.*)&type=(.*)$ /$1/$2/$3 permanent;
   rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?tag=$1&page=1 last;
}
```

but it didnt work..

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49191594/nginx-rewrite-a-lot-2000-of-urls-with-parameters/49192527#49192527)

Comment: what about the variables? what should I write for the redirect? I tried but still not workin..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `rewrite` and `location` directives use a normalized URI which does not include the query string.

To test the query string, you will need to consult the `$request_uri` or `$args` variable using an `if` statement and/or `map` directive.

The advantage of using `$request_uri` is that it contains the original request and will help to avoid a redirection loop.

If you only have one redirection to perform, the `map` solution is probably overfill.

Try:

```
if ($request_uri ~ ^/index\.php\?tag=(.*)&section=(.*)&type=(.*)$) {
    return 301 /$1/$2/$3;
}
location / {
    ...
}
```

See [this caution](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) on the use of `if`.

Comment: thanks, this is exactly what I am lookin for.. and I just realized should put the code outside the location..