# Nginx mapping with regex does not accept query string

Tags: node.js, nginx, nginx-config, nginx-location

I am trying to redirect some URLs which have query string. My problem is that Nginx regex ignores question mark in the URLs, so my regex fails matching if there is a question mark in middle of URLs.

something like this:

```
/product/list/mfr/%D9%86%D9%88%DA%A9%DB%8C%D8%A7-nokia?inc_subs=1&manufacturer_id=25&page=6
```

redirect to this URL:

```
/product/list/69_70_80/nokia-mobile
```

I tried:

```
map $uri $new_uri {

~^/(product/list/mfr)/   /product/list/69_70_80/nokia-mobile
}
```

it works but it's not accurate because I have other URLs that will match with this regex which I don't want.

I also tried this:

```
location ~/product/list/mfr/(\S+)page=6$ {
    return 301 https://www.example.com/product/list/69_70_80/nokia-mobile;
    }
```

regex101 says it matches, but when I try in browser it does not redirect. The only character that ruins it is the question mark.  If I only delete the question mark, it works!!

regex101 link:
https://regex101.com/r/UvXZF0/1/

It's been hell of a problem and headache, I really appreciate it if anybody can solve it

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54329332/nginx-redirect-url-with-query-strings/54330947#54330947).

Comment: Thanks man it works, you saved me @RichardSmith

Comment: Also, I have to say the exact answer to my problem was another answer of yours in the comments of the link you shared : [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49192527/12092482) @RichardSmith

Comment: That other answer is certainly the preferred solution if you have more than one redirect to implement.

Comment: @RichardSmith Yes that is one of the reasons