# How to write redirect rule in Nginx

Tags: nginx, redirect, rules

We have a specific URL with query string, that we want to redirect to other url. In .htaccess that is working fine but don't know how to write it in Nginx config file.

Here is URL -  `BaseURL/index.php?page=HOME`

This should be redirect to  -  `BaseUrl/MyCustomDir/`

Here is code I tried, but it's not working:

```
location = /index.php?page=HOME {
       return 301 https://BaseUrl/MyCustomDir/ ;
}
```

And:

```
rewrite ^/index.php?page=HOME$ https://BaseUrl/MyCustomDir/ redirect;
```

One by one, but both not working for me. How can I fix this? It's all I tried in `server{ }`.

Comment: See [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49192527/4862445) or [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54330947/4862445).